# Trying to login on a registered SHA1 Password

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've made recently a register and login with php for my website, but it's having a issue that i just can't handle..
Whenever i try to protect my pass with any modes, it just says that the login is incorrect.

Here the part of the code i use for passwords

Register:

```
if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error[] = 'Please Enter Your Password ';
} else {
$password = $_POST['password'];
}
...
$password2 = SHA1($password);
$query = "INSERT INTO member( username, email, password, hwid) VALUES ( '$username', '$email', '$password2', '$hwid')";
```

Then, in login:

```
$pass = addslashes(SHA1($_GET['password']));
...
$passwort = $row->password;
$id = $row->hwid;
if ($passwort == $pass && $id == $hwid)
```

So, what am i doing wrong, from having a failed login?
When i use no hash, it works good..

Comment: Print the values of `$pass` and `$passwort`. Are they what you expect?

Comment: Why the two mysql extension tags for your question, and where's your SHA1 function?

Comment: Problems here: 1. why uppercase PHP functions (though PHP is case-insensitive); 2. why `addslashes()`? 3. `$_GET` or `$_POST`?

Comment: If i remove addslashes(), i continue having the issues.. :(
And, its because.. the register is from web, and the login.. from an application

Comment: But.. whats the problem with the code? I already tried to use just
    $pass = SHA1($_GET['password']);

Comment: Is your login form method GET or POST, that will make the difference and does it contain named attributes? Plus, check to see if your column is VARCHAR and long enough to accomodate the hash.

Comment: It worked! Thanks Fred!It was the column that was not long enough

Comment: You're welcome. I've posted my answer. @Leonardo

Answer (score 2):

If your login form method is POST instead of GET, that will make the difference and needs to contain named attributes. *This is just an insight.*

Plus, check to see if your column is VARCHAR and is long enough to accomodate the hash.

- Many a time, that is the issue and I've seen it happen often.

I also recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

SHA1 isn't the best hashing method, and uses a fixed hash (making it easier to crack) instead of a random hash like `password_hash()`.

Comment: @JohnConde Isn't it *always* the case? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In register, try changing

```
$password2 = SHA1($password);
```

to this:

```
$password2 = SHA1(add_slashes($password));
```